# what are the python People API 'updateContact' format & content of the function arguments

Tags: python, google-api

I am confused by how to update a contact using python.
According to the Google's People API, the function is

```
updateContact(resourceName=None, body=*, x__xgafv=None, updatePersonFields=None)
```

I have a contact by the name of Charles Babbage:

```
{'etag': '%EgYBAj0KNy4aBAECBQciDHRIenJLZkEzM0hBPQ==',
 'names': [{'displayName': 'Charles Babbage',
            'displayNameLastFirst': 'Babbage, Charles',
            'familyName': 'Babbage',
            'givenName': 'Charles',
            'metadata': {'primary': True,
                         'source': {'id': '216ee27389bd1ef4',
                                    'type': 'CONTACT'}}}],
 'nicknames': [{'metadata': {'primary': True,
                             'source': {'id': '216ee27389bd1ef4',
                                        'type': 'CONTACT'}},
                'value': 'charlie'}],
 'resourceName': 'people/c2409111836549783284'}
```

When I do a 'get' to get his nickname, the result is:

```
{'etag': '%EgQBCjcuGgQBAgUHIgx0SHpyS2ZBMzNIQT0=',
 'nicknames': [{'metadata': {'primary': True,
                             'source': {'id': '216ee27389bd1ef4',
                                        'type': 'CONTACT'}},
                'value': 'charlie'}],
 'resourceName': 'people/c2409111836549783284'}
```

I wish to update Charles Babbage nickname from `'charlie'` to `'charlesB'`

I have tried many variations for what  `"body=*"` could be and what `"updatePersonFields"` could be, including

- making `'body1' = whole person`, making `body1 = whole person` with a new value for nickname
- making `'nicknames'` in the `updatePersonFields` to be `'nicknames'` or an object similar to what the `'get'` returns but with a changed nickname value.

While my update code executes without error with `contactId` of the form `'people/c.........'`, I don't get the change I want

```
result = service.people().updateContact(resourceName = contactId, body = body1, updatePersonFields = 'nicknames')
```

Comment: From what I can see from the [sample update request](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/write-people#update-an-existing-contact), the important part is to include both `etag` and `resourceName` in the `body` dictionary, and `nicknames` should just be a list of `{'value': ...}` dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you Martijn.  I think my confusion is what is the content of "body=*" and what is the content of "updatePersonFields".  Should body be the 'person' returned from a 'connections' list?  and updatePersonFields a new nicknames object based on the previous?

Comment: All we have to go by is the [REST API documentation](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/updateContact), which states that *the request body contains an instance of Person.*, and the example from the guide I linked to, which only includes the field that is being updated.

Comment: Thank you, Martijn, you comments lead me to a working solution, which I will now publish

Answer (score 1):

A solution that worked is as follows:

1. get the contact (it will be a list)

   ```
   aContact = service.people().get(
       resourceName = 'people/c.....',
       personFields = 'nicknames'
   ).execute()
   ```
2. Change the value of the first element of contact list.

   ```
   NickNames = aContact['nicknames'][0]        
   NickNames['value'] = 'newNickName'
   ```
3. change `aContact` with new info

   ```
   aContact['nicknames'] = NickNames
   ```
4. `updateContact`

   ```
   result = service.people().updateContact(
       'resourceName' = 'people/c....',
       body = aContact, 
       updatePersonFields = 'nicknames'
   ).execute()
   ```

   Note: `body` is the changed contact and `updatePersonFields` is just the name of the field that is changed.

Comment: Should there be a `.execute()` on the `service.people().updateContact(...)` return value?

Comment: Thanks @martijnPieters

Comment: I had issues with this until I realized that I was using a read-only scope which was giving me a 403 error. Make sure that ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts'] is included in your scopes. If people are doing their oath login with a .pickle file as the quickstart guide suggests, that means they will need to regenerate that file with the correct scope.