# How to read a Google People api response object [updated]

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

I'm new to Google's API and I'm having trouble reading the content of a People contact.

To get the details of a particular contact, references show this code should work [Edit: I updated the personfields]:

```
  profile = service.people().get(resourceName='people/c63810788897573286', personFields='names')
```

The resourceName is the ID of a particular contact (that ID will only work for someone with access to my account). The server grabs it correctly and returns this:

<googleapiclient.discovery.Resource object at 0x10fd183c8>

How do I read the content of this object? I can't figure out from the [documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/people_v1.people.html#get)

I want to print out the Name. I'm pretty new to APIs, so maybe there is a standard way to read an HTTP object or maybe it's something unique to Google's API. Thanks for any advice

Comment: Testing your request parameters returns an error 400 on the online API tester as seen [here](https://imgur.com/a/MDfU2Cn). It looks like the _displayName_ under the **personFields** list of parameters doesn't exist on the official [docs](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get?apix_params=%7B%22resourceName%22%3A%22people%2Fc2385402682961512987%22%2C%22personFields%22%3A%22displayName%22%7D#query-parameters). Have you tried converting the returned object into a [string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-json-to-string/) to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: Thanks. i updated the personfield's name.Still having the same problem. Converting it to a json string gets this error "TypeError: Object of type method is not JSON serializable"

Comment: nevermind. found an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer in another [somewhat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54970387/what-are-the-python-people-api-updatecontact-format-content-of-the-function) related StackOverflow. I needed to the add .execute() to the call

```
profile = service.people().get(resourceName='people/c63810788897573286', personFields='names').execute()
```